# How to make a program run only when there is Internet connection using batch or powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, batch-file

The question may sound stupid but I 've been trying to do it for hours now.

The thing is that, I want a batch file to check for internet connction every **30 seconds** and if there is no connection, I want it to **check for it again.**

If the connection is available, I want it to start a program let's say Notepad.exe.

I can also use **powershell**, but I am a bit unfamiliar with that but I would be glad if it colud do the job.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include the code you've tried in your question, and tell us what problems you had with it.

Comment: You could try something using "ping". This should work with batch files as well as powershell. Here's a link to something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656667/5594257

Comment: Here is a HTA named as [Check_Internet_Connection.hta](https://pastebin.com/yyewJYwW)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1) to check if you can reach a certain website. This is basically the powershell equivalent of ping.

```bsh
while (-not (Test-Connection google.com -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
Start-Process notepad.exe
```

Comment: Note: You can also use ``(ping -t google.fr -n 1).Count -eq "1"`` in your condition

Comment: @Xiaojiba That is correct. However when I have the luxury to use powershell instead of batch, using a cmdlet is a lot more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The usual option is to decide for yourself how an active internet connection should look and act like and check accordingly. One way would be to use `ping` or `Test-Connection`, however that won't tell you when something other than DNS or ICMP is broken. You could also download a small resource somewhere and if it succeeds, an internet connection is apparently present. This could be done with `curl`, `wget`, or `Invoke-WebRequest`.

In a batch file you'd most likely check the exit code of the command (via `if errorlevel` or `%errorlevel%`) or just chain commands together with `||` and `&&`.

In PowerShell you can usually deduce failure or success a lot easier when using the respective cmdlets.

Answer (score 1):

Using basic ping, but considering that ping is for diagnostics and does not get priority.

```
@echo off
:try
(ping 8.8.8.8 && start notepad)>nul 2>&1 || echo No connection
(timeout 30 /NOBREAK)>nul
goto :try
```

or by using curl:

```
@echo off
:try
(curl google.com && start notepad)>nul 2>&1 || echo No connection
(timeout 30 /NOBREAK)>nul
goto :try
```

Comment: Good work, it's nice to see the batch/cmd version of this. Reminds me why I love Powershell.